# Conditioning with respect to functions of random variables

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation

If we have a probability space $\left(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P \right)$ and a measureable space $\left(U, \Sigma \right)$, then for any two random variables $X,Y: \Omega \to U$ under what conditions on a function $f$ can we say that

$$\mathbb E\left(X \;|\;Y\right) = \mathbb E\left(X \; | f(Y) \right)\;? $$

I tried rewriting the expectations in terms of their $\sigma$-algebras.
By definition we have that $\mathbb E\left(X \; | f(Y) \right) := \mathbb E\left(X \; | \sigma(f(Y)) \right)$ where
$$\sigma(f(Y)) = \{S\in\mathcal F \; : \;S = f(Y)^{-1}(B),\; B\in \Sigma\}.$$

So in this case the two expectations will be equal if $Y$ and $f(Y)$ generate the same $\sigma$-field. I think I can see how this will be the case if $f^{-1}$ exists, and $\Sigma$ is closed under both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ , however are there more general conditions under which this holds?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would $f^{-1}$ be necessarily measurable? Or are you assuming that with existence?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I think thats part of what I meant when I said 'closed'

Comment: If you want the (presumably measurable) function $f$ to work for any $X,Y$, you can define $X=Y$ to conclude $Y=E[Y|Y]=E[Y|f(Y)] = g(f(Y))$ for some measurable $g$, so $Y$ and $f(Y)$ must generate the same sigma algebras. And in particular we can claim $f$ is injective over the restricted domain $Y(\Omega)$. [By the way I assume the equality $E[X|Y]=E[X|f(Y)]$ means that  $Z$ is a version of $E[X|Y]$ if and only if $Z$ is a version of $E[X|f(Y)]$.]